# How to select multiple fields from a single column and output to a single row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

New to sql and new to stack, so I'm sorry if this is a duplicate question.  I'm so new I'm not even sure how to phrase the question, or if it is possible.

```
table1
-----------------------------
|  table2.key  |   codes    |
-----------------------------
|  1           |   'pizza'  |
-----------------------------
|  1           |   'cheese' |
-----------------------------
|  2           |   'pizza'  |
-----------------------------
|  3           |   'zebra'  |

table2
-------------------
|  key |  name    |
-------------------
|  1   |  'steve' |
-------------------
|  2   |  'john'  |
-------------------
|  3   |  'ralph  |
```

Not sure how to compose a select statement for what I want, so I'll show you what I would like for my output to be from the above tables

```
Desired output
------------------------------------
|  key  |  Name | cPizza  | cCheese|
------------------------------------
|   1   |'steve'| 'pizza'|'cheese' |
------------------------------------
|   2   |'john' | 'pizza'|  ''     |
------------------------------------
|   3   |'ralph'|   ''   |   ''    |
```

My case is more complex than this.  I need to return a single row for each id, but everything I write returns multiple rows for each code.

I want to return everyone from table2 and show if they have pizza or cheese codes. If they don't leave them blank.

Comment: you will need to have a table with the pizza codes.... sql won't know zebra until you reference it to the table of codes otherwise it will be a massive case or iif statement... and a LEFT join should solve this

Comment: What should your query do if a new row were to be added in table 1 {1,"ham"}

Comment: Also, why does "zebra" not show up for Ralph?

Comment: You want to simply repeat the column name if the `codes` value is `pizza` or `cheese` ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a query that will give you your results. This isn't very scalable but without knowing the actual use case, this will get you the desired results from your example.

Creating test data:

```
DECLARE @table1 TABLE (
    tbl_key INT,
    codes NVARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT @table1 VALUES
(1, 'pizza'),
(1, 'cheese'),
(2, 'pizza'),
(3, 'zebra')

DECLARE @table2 TABLE (
    tbl_key INT,
    name NVARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT @table2 VALUES
(1, 'steve'),
(2, 'john'),
(3, 'ralph')
```

Query:

```
SELECT
    tbl2.tbl_key AS [key],
    tbl2.name AS [Name],
    ISNULL(pizza_tbl.codes, '') AS cPizza,
    ISNULL(cheese_tbl.codes, '') AS cCheese
FROM @table2 tbl2
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        tbl_key,
        codes
    FROM @table1 tbl1
    WHERE codes = 'cheese'
    ) cheese_tbl ON
    tbl2.tbl_key = cheese_tbl.tbl_key
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        tbl_key,
        codes
    FROM @table1 tbl1
    WHERE codes = 'pizza'
    ) pizza_tbl ON
    tbl2.tbl_key = pizza_tbl.tbl_key
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a shorter version of of what you need

```
DECLARE @table1 TABLE (
    tbl_key INT,
    codes NVARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT @table1 VALUES
(1, 'pizza'),
(1, 'cheese'),
(2, 'pizza'),
(3, 'zebra')

DECLARE @table2 TABLE (
    tbl_key INT,
    name NVARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT @table2 VALUES
(1, 'steve'),
(2, 'john'),
(3, 'ralph')


select distinct a.tbl_key as [key] ,a.Name ,isnull(ab.codes,'') as cPizza,isnull(ac.codes,'') as cCheese,isnull(ad.codes,'') as cZebra
from @table2 a 

outer apply (select codes from @table1 where a.tbl_key = tbl_key and codes = 'pizza') as ab 
outer apply (select codes from @table1 where a.tbl_key = tbl_key and codes = 'cheese') as ac 
outer apply (select codes from @table1 where a.tbl_key = tbl_key and codes = 'zebra') as ad
```

Comment: Could you please point out *why* and *how* this solves the OPs issue? While it may technically answer the OPs question, just some pasted code is not a *good* answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the values of `codes` in advance you can convert rows to columns with the [PIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) operator. The following query :

```
select tbl_key,name,[pizza] ,[cheese] 
from ( select t2.tbl_key,t2.name,t1.codes
       from table1 t1 inner join table2 t2 on t1.tbl_key=t2.tbl_key
     ) as source
PIVOT 
(
    MAX(codes)
    FOR codes in ([cheese],[pizza])
) as pvt
```

Will return

```
tbl_key name    pizza   cheese
1       steve   pizza   cheese
2       john    pizza   NULL
3       ralph   NULL    NULL
```

You can change the name of the columns or replace NULL with an empty string :

```
select tbl_key,name,ISNULL([pizza],'') as cPizza ,ISNULL([cheese],'') as cCheese
from ( select t2.tbl_key,t2.name,t1.codes
       from table1 t1 inner join table2 t2 on t1.tbl_key=t2.tbl_key
     ) as source
PIVOT 
(
    MAX(codes)
    FOR codes in ([cheese],[pizza])
) as pvt
```

The PIVOT operator calculates an aggregate for each of a set of values and exposes it as a column, using the values name. In the case, for the `cheese` and `pizza` values it calculates `MAX(codes)`, essentially the value itself, and exposes it as `cheese` and `pizza` columns.